# Bus error: 10 when using NSLog with DoraemonKit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `DoraemonKit` for debugging purposes. My `NSLOG` calls catching by `DoraemonKit`. I am getting crash reports from some of my users and I couldn't figure it out.

**Crash log:**

```
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001e1622e2c _platform_memset + 140
1   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a75a34cc small_malloc_should_clear + 1352 (magazine_small.c:0)
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a759fd38 szone_malloc_should_clear + 136 (magazine_malloc.c:238)
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001a75ae618 _malloc_zone_calloc + 88 (malloc.c:1546)
4   Foundation                      0x000000019946abf8 -[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] + 544 (NSJSONSerialization.m:2279)
5   Foundation                      0x000000019946a900 +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 76 (NSJSONSerialization.m:2459)
6   DoraemonKit                     0x000000010ba7ffa4 -[NSDictionary(DoraemonUnicodeReadable) descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 1024
7   Foundation                      0x0000000199564640 _NS_os_log_callback + 288 (NSPlatform.m:187)
8   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001ae4cf15c _os_log_fmt_flatten_NSCF + 64 (format.m:54)
9   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001ae4ce908 _os_log_fmt_flatten_object + 216 (format.m:316)
10  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001ae4db940 _os_log_impl_flatten_and_send + 1736 (format.c:799)
11  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00000001ae4de524 _os_log_with_args_impl + 388 (log.c:2604)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001981f39ec _CFLogvEx3 + 188 (CFUtilities.c:1224)
13  Foundation                      0x0000000199566b84 _NSLogv + 108 (NSPlatform.m:0)
14  Foundation                      0x0000000199566be0 NSLog + 56 (NSPlatform.m:1321)
15  MyApp                       0x0000000106a3b914 -[Manager handleReceivedData:] + 72 (Manager.m:119)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019816d9a0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 28 (CFNotificationCenter.c:706)
```

**My Code:**

```
- (void)handleReceivedData:(NSNotification *)notify {
    NSDictionary *receivedDic = [notify userInfo];
    
    NSLog(@"receivedDicbt: %@",receivedDic);
```

It is pretty basic, actually. I am catching an `NSNotification` and printing to `NSLOG`.
Then `DoraemonKit` catches it, as you can see in the stack trace.

I've inspected the `DoraemonKit`  and found the Frame 6's file; it is here:

https://github.com/didi/DoKit/blob/bf05430692e7b549f4b89d2abec877cd79dafaf4/iOS/DoraemonKit/Src/Core/Category/Foundation%2BDoraemon.m#L45

**Exception Type:**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
```

What can cause to this problem and how to resolve it?